# Why would you put covers in front of the output of the condenser fan on these mini-split units?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, hvac

[image]

Seems like this would be bad for airflow and hurt efficiency? I'd think you would want to blow that hot exhaust air as far away from the intake as possible, and with as little static pressure as possible on the output side of the coil.

But they do seem like a manufactured product rather than a hack a misguided person put in, so am I missing something?

Comment: Heat from sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

They are fragile and easily damaged, so it is common practice to protect them with shrouds. Those shrouds also serve to guide the airflow from the fans that blow air over the coils to maximize heat transfer efficiency, if so equipped, as well as prevent the sun's rays from heating them up as pointed out by DKNguyen.

Comment: "Guide airflow"? The fans are behind the coils and blow the air straight though the coils and out... where the airflow then directly hits these baffles. Seems like worst case airflow management besides just sealing the output path completely.

Comment: "prevent the sun's rays from heating them up"? I thought we had long ago debunked the idea that shading condenser coils has any significant benefit?...
https://blog.directenergy.com/shading-air-conditioner-myths/#:~:text=We%20debunk%20this%20common%20myth,reduce%20the%20condenser's%20cooling%20efficiency.

Comment: "They are fragile and easily damaged, so it is common practice to protect them with shrouds" Protect them from what? The shrouds are plastic, the guards they are covering are metal. Remember that the airflow is outward so not like debris is going to get sucked in here.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would you put covers in front of the output of the condenser fan
> on these mini-split units?

1. Weed eaters.
2. Leaf blowers.
3. Spray painters.
4. Pressure washers.
5. Accident prone groundskeepers with pruners, clippers, rakes, pretty much anything - you'd be amazed at the damage they can do.
6. Kids playing hide and seek in the bushes.
7. To reduce the thermal footprint and not have hot air blown out into the sidewalk.
8. Cosmetics - you can paint them to match the building.
9. To prevent strong winds from stalling (or backdriving) the fan. You don't want the fan spinning when the unit is off, it wears out the bearings.

Don't worry about the efficiency, the change won't be measurable, and it basically doesn't matter if the unit can't survive the environment.

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned, it is to provide protection against strong winds directly entering the air outlet.
As for the gap, it does seems small but that's what the manufacturers decided to go with.

This information is stated on the equipament installation manual.
https://www.mitsubishitechinfo.ca/sites/default/files/SB_CM_SG-1%28RE%29%28SD%29_PUMY_N%28H%29%28K%29MU_P-Series_201705.pdf